# How do I specialize this template member function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have this setup:

```
class DontUse;

template<class T,class U = DontUse, class V = SomeStandardType>
class Foo
{
   public:
     void bar(U &uh);
};
```

When U is set to DontUse, I want bar to be an empty function. In all other cases, I want bar to have some implementation. I tried doing this using specialization, but this code (which I realize is somehow incorrect) doesn't compile:

```
template<class T,class V> void Foo<T,DontUse,V>::bar(DontUse &none){}
template<class T,class U,class V> void Foo<T,U,V>::bar(U &uh)
{
  //do something here
}
```

The error message is this (MSVC10):

```
1>path_to_project: error C2244: 'Foo<T,U,V>::bar' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

and it points to the line of the first template specialization.

How do I do this correctly?

Here's the actual code, although it's reduced to the minimalist part that's relevant:

```
    struct DontUse;

    template<typename Derived, typename Renderer =  DontUse, typename TimeType = long>
    class Gamestate
    {
    public:

        void Render(Renderer &r);

    };

    template<typename Derived, typename TimeType> void Gamestate<Derived, DontUse,TimeType>::Render( DontUse){}
    template<typename Derived, typename Renderer, typename TimeType> void Gamestate<Derived,Renderer,TimeType>::Render(Renderer &r)
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->Render(r);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the definition of your specialized class?

Comment: @Nate: Yep, I put it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specialize individual members of a template. You have to specialize the class itself:

```
class DontUse;

template<class T, class V>
class Foo<T, DontUse, V>
{
   public:
     void bar(DontUse)
     { }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to just use this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A, class B, class C>
struct S
{
    void foo(B& b)
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_same<U, DontUse>::value, "Bad Boy!");
    }
};
```

Or, if you really want a empty function, just use an if.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A, class B, class C>
struct S
{
    void foo(B& b)
    {
         if(!std::is_same<U, DontUse>::value)
         {
              //all code goes here
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing it like that is not sufficient. The point is to make it possible for the user to instantiate a Derived<Gamestate> that doesn't actually do any rendering (For example for serverside programming). I could just have the user leave that function implemented but empty, but doing it my way would be a little more comfortable, I think. By the way, I'll acceppt Bo Persson's answer, since technically he answered my question more precisely (how to specialize the thing) and gave code.

Comment: @heishe With is_same you're able to do anything you want. Throw exception, call another function, etc. I don't see you're problem here.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now. Just do void Render(Renderer &r) { if(is_same<...>::value) { do nothing } else {do default stuff}}. Still, I asked a follow-up question to this question over here, which asks if this is somehow possible at compile-time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503042/how-do-i-select-an-alternative-member-function-implementation-depending-on-a-te#comment12033196_9503042

Comment: I don't think your solution would work after all, since in "do default stuff" I would have to use functions of the given template type, which DontUse obviously doesn't possess (which leads to a compile error).

Comment: I still don't get your problem, but the answer on the other question seems to be the best you can get, so go with that. I didn't even know myself that that is possible. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that. A member function of a class template is not itself a separate template, and cannot be specialized (partially or fully) independently of the class template.

You need to define a partial specialization of the class template `Foo`, give it a `bar` member function, and define that.