# How do I select an alternative member function implementation, depending on a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have this class:

```
template</*some other parameters here */class toggle>
class Foo
{
   void function();
   //Lots of other non-parametrized member functions
}
```

Now, if toggle is of some certain type, I want function to use an alternative implementation, and for all other cases I want it to use the standard implementation. This should be done completely at compile time, since outside users of the class should be able to instantiate this template that (intentionally, in order to save memory and a little performance) lacks some functionality.

The catch: Simply specializing the whole class is not realistic, since Foo will have a lot of other methods which don't depend on this toggle, which would also have to be implemented again, making everything a huge waste of space.

Comment: You could use inheritance and polymorphism, couldn't you?

Comment: Not at compile time. A classic implementation of the strategy pattern would introduce just those performance slow-downs that I'm trying to avoid (virtual functions, etc.). Ideally, if toggle is some type that determines that function should be the alternative implementation, I'd like to have the function() disappear completely, although I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class toggle>
class Foo
{
public:
    void function() { std::cout << "Default\n"; }
};

template <>
void Foo<int>::function() { std::cout << "int\n"; }

int main ()
{
    Foo<std::string>().function();
    Foo<int>().function();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Default
int
```

Comment: I thought it wasn't possible to specialize template class members?

Comment: @heishe: this is an example of *explicit specialization*. It's a little strict: it needs to happen outside the `class {}` scope, and it needs to be complete specialization with no parameters inside the `template<>`. But it does exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: Mhm... then I have to broaden the question a little, since my template has a couple of additional parameters.

Comment: @heishe: Yes, I just mean that the special `function` can't depend on (vary with) the parameters — it's really just a regular function. The general case can vary. Otherwise you can turn `function` into a separate, nested function template with its own parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You might get away with specializing a base class instead:

```
template<class toggle>
class FooFunction {
public:
    void function();
};

template<>
class FooFunction<blah> {
public:
    void function();
};

template<class toggle>
class Foo : public FooFunction<toggle> {
    //Lots of other non-parametrized member functions
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If making `function` an overloaded set of function templates is acceptable to you, then:

```
// toggle is not a dependent type so we solve that
template<
    typename T = toggle
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<T, int>::value
    >::type
>
void function()
{ /* implementation for int */ }

template<
    typename T = toggle
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<T, int>::value
    >::type
    // dummy parameter to make this declaration distinct from the previous one
    typename = void
>
void function()
{ /* implementation for others */ }
```

This is written with a C++11 style but can be made to work with C++03. (This may rely on SFINAE being somewhat of a grey area for C++03 in some cases, but I don't know enough about the rules.)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly function has to be part of the class.

Comment: @heishe This is, otherwise `toggle` wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Template specialisation, try debugging this, and note that not all functions need specialising:

```
template <class T> class Spec
{
public:
    void Func()
    {
    }

    void Func2()
    {
    }

};


void Spec<double>::Func()
{

}

int main( int argc, char *argv )
{

    Spec<int> spec1;
    spec1.Func();
    spec1.Func2();

    Spec<double> spec2;
    spec2.Func();
    spec2.Func2();


    return 0;
}
```